# Python list comprehension - getting only one result in inner loop

Tags: python

I have a traditional for loop, that I want to convert to a list comprehension, to be more Pythonic. For the inner loop, I want only one result, then proced to the next iteration of the outer loop.

```
    for tableStartIdx in tableStartIdxs:
        for lineIdx, line in enumerate(lines[tableStartIdx:], tableStartIdx):
            if '|}' == line:
                print(lines[lineIdx])
                return
```

Here's the closest I've gotten with a list comprehension:

```
next((lineIdx for tableStartIdx in tableStartIdxs for lineIdx, line in enumerate(lines[tableStartIdx:], tableStartIdx) if '|}' == line), -1)
```

However, this stops the outer loop when I identify the first result. I thought I would shorten what's include in the `next()` function, but this results in "Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument." Makes sense.

Is what I'm doing even possible with list comprehension? Or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: "I have a traditional for loop, that I want to convert to a list comprehension, to be more Pythonic." Pythonic does not mean replace all for-loops with list-comprehensions...

Comment: As [readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), it would be more pythonic not to try to convert your perfectly readable loop into some obscure list comprehension.

Comment: Also, that is a generator expression, not a list-comprehension.

Comment: The obvious thing you are missing is that you shouldn't be aiming for a list comprehension for the sake of it.

Comment: I'm not sure your for-loop does what you say, shouldn't it be a `continue` instead of `return`?